# Crashed curl comes to server

Tags: node.js, express, curl

Im have a curl post request to my srver, and her body dont parse correct

Its a curl req from service

```
curl -d '{"merchantAccount":"pipedrive_youscore_rubicon_ltd","orderReference":"WFP-BTN-7181819-635e48482b33d","merchantSignature":"7bf****************c","amount":3,"currency":"UAH","authCode":"326470","email":"rubicon.sergii@gmail.com","phone":"380669114250","createdDate":1667123272,"processingDate":1667123284,"cardPan":"44****6705","cardType":"Visa","issuerBankCountry":"Ukraine","issuerBankName":"MONObank","recToken":"","transactionStatus":"Approved","reason":"Ok","reasonCode":1100,"fee":0.07,"paymentSystem":"googlePay","acquirerBankName":"WayForPay","cardProduct":"credit","clientName":"Rubicon Sergii","products":[{"name":"\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0439 \u0442\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0440","price":3,"count":1}],"clientFields":[{"name":"\u0414\u043e\u043c\u0435\u043d \u043f\u043e\u0440\u0442\u0430\u043b\u0443","value":"rawgsag"}]}' http://app.rubicon.tips:3000/checkSupPay
```

And this is the response to the request:

```
'{"merchantAccount":"pipedrive_youscore_rubicon_ltd","orderReference":"WFP-BTN-7181819-6361151577ee8","merchantSignature":"5f0f*************bc6536a98dd","amount":3,"currency":"UAH","authCode":"126496","email":null,"phone":null,"createdDate":1667306773,"processingDate":1667307818,"cardPan":"","cardType":null,"issuerBankCountry":null,"issuerBankName":null,"recToken":"","transactionStatus":"Refunded","reason":"Ok","reasonCode":1100,"fee":0,"paymentSystem":"googlePay","acquirerBankName":"WayForPay","cardProduct":"credit","clientName":null,"products":': {
    '{"name":"\\u0422\\u0435\\u0441\\u0442\\u043e\\u0432\\u0438\\u0439 \\u0442\\u043e\\u0432\\u0430\\u0440","price":3,"count":1}': {
      '{"name":"\\u0414\\u043e\\u043c\\u0435\\u043d \\u043f\\u043e\\u0440\\u0442\\u0430\\u043b\\u0443","value":"qh34hh44h"}': ''
    }
  }
}
```

Im trying to decode this req with

```
bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })
```

and `bodyParser.json()` but its doest work(

Comment: If you want to post JSON data, you have to set the respective header .. `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Comment: So you do not see how the response is a problem?  Did you make a mistake copying the response to you post?  The response, as posted, cannot be encoded becasue it is a broken string.   But yes it does look likely you have a problem with your request too.  I want to be able to encode the current response to see what is wrong with it.  If you want to manually encode the response and paste it in you answer, that would be helpful.  I do not have the time ($$$) to manually encode it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your content type is currently:

```
'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

You should change your data or your content type.

If the data is required to be JSON then add -H 'Content-Type: application/json

But if it is working then it does not matter.

But you problem is most likely your JSON is malformed.

Look at the end of the lines:

```
"clientName":null,"products":': {
"price":3,"count":1}': {
"value":"qh34hh44h"}': ''
```

The characters at the end of the line are not included in the string.

The end of the first two lines the `: {` are not part of the string.
At the end of the third line `: ''` is not in the string.

Comment: I think, problem in req.body, this req sending me a payment service, and i cant change a conent type. He send me a json object in req.body, where req content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', and i dont know how to correctly parse this body